# Issue in pm2 - It stops responding

Tags: node.js, server, pm2

Am facing issue in my application servers. Assume that - there are two nodes in the Load-balancer.

Suddenly one of the node from them becomes unhealthy.

When I logged in that instance. There were no logs coming in pm2. 
then I check its CPU it was very high.

So please guide me how can I fix this issue. Or any way to debug it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [flame graphs](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/uncategorized/profiling-node-js/) to see where your Node app is CPU bound.

You can also use the [new debugging system in Node 6.3](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27) (`--inspect`) to debug with the full power of [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

PM2 has some limited protection for runaway issues like this via the `max-memory-restart` option. Typically, high CPU will also correlate with high memory usage and this option can be used to restart your app when it begins consuming large amounts of memory (which in your case may or may not be the correct moment but it should help).

```
--max-memory-restart <memory>  specify max memory amount used to autorestart (in octet or use syntax like 100M)
```